# Angular 6 bulk operation on all ticked rows in a table

Tags: angular, html, typescript

In an Angular 6 web app I have a table where each row has a checkbox.
I want to perform bulk operations on ticked rows, for example delete.

I was thinking on adding an isSelected bool to the data model, then do a foreach on all the ticked rows, then I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35595544/angular-loop-through-table-row-and-check-for-checked-checbox/35597614) on Stackoverflow which is similar, but look like it deals with AngularJS rather than 6.

Can anyone suggest the 'best' way to go about it in Angular 6?

I haven't started coding this yet as I didn't know if the approach in the linked post would be ok for angular or if I'd be wasting my time.

Comment: What have you done so far? Apart from the posts that you mentioned in your question? Something similar can be done actually. doesn't matter if it's AngularJS or Angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this is to first create an array:

```
checkarray: any[] = [];
```

When evere you check something in your table this array will be filled or emptied:

```
checkbox(item: any, event) {
        if (event.ctrlKey) {
            if (this.checkarray.find(x => x.ID == item.ID)) {
                this.checkarray.splice(this.checkarray.indexOf(item), 1);
            }
            else {
                this.checkarray.push(item);
            }
        }
        else {
            this.checkarray.splice(0);
            this.checkarray.push(item);
        }
    }
```

When you want to delete items from DB you simply send your array to server and do your stuff.

Comment: @DarkW1nter In this example, I use "CTRL" for multiple checking. If you check on checked item, it will be unchecked and deleted from array. If you like my approach, please accept my answer.